# Java runtime method overriding rules

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding

What are java runtime overriding rules for below 2 scenarios

**Scenario 1 :**

```
class A{   
void display(Integer i){
       sysout("In A Integer");
   } 

void display(Object obj){
       sysout("In A Object");
   }
}    
class B extends A{
    void display(int i){
       sysout("In B int");
   }
}    
PSVM(){
   A a=new B(); 
   a.display(2); //In A Integer
   a.display(new Integer(2));  //In A Integer
   a.display("hello"); //In A Object
   a.display(new Object()); //In A Object
   a.display(null);
}
```

**Scenario 2 :**

```
class A {
    void display(int i){
       sysout("In A int");
   }
}

class B extends A{
   void display(Integer i){
       sysout("In B Integer");
   }
   void display(Object obj){
       sysout("In B Object");
   }
}

PSVM(){
   A a=new B();
   a.display(2); //In A int
   a.display(new Integer(2)); //In A int
   a.display("hello"); // Compilation error
   a.display(new Object()); //Compilation error
   a.display(null); //Compilation error
}
```

I have few queries here :
1. How does general runtime override methods evaluation happens: Any reference available ?
2. Why in Scenario 2, a.display(new Intger(2)) not throwing compilation error ?

Comment: 2. why do you think it should create one?

Comment: In both the scenarios, B object is assigned to A reference. IN these scenarios, in which order runtime method invocation is done ?

Comment: Hint: when uploading code, then put examples there are consistent; like: other people can simply copy/paste it into their editor to play with it. Your examples use some PSVM() constructor call; and then you are using "sysout" which is a method that doesn't exist. In other words: you have a concrete-code question. Then paste real code, not pseudo-code!

Comment: And hint: details are important. Exceptions are **thrown**, but the compiler gives you error messages. It seems that you do not understand that these are two different things!

Comment: let's say for understanding -  JAVA tries to match the closest possible `Data type` in the parameter (given) to the parameters declared (overriden) by the called method.

Comment: Hint: please let me know if my input is helpful for you (for example by accepting my answer); or if you are looking for additional information.

Answer (score 1):

First question: you can find the rules for **overriding** within this tutorial from [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html). Another good starting point might be that [site](http://www.codejava.net/java-core/the-java-language/12-rules-of-overriding-in-java-you-should-know). Of course, if you are looking for a **spec**, then only the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8) does the job.

On your second question:

```
a.display(new Integer(2)); //In A int
```

That works because the compiler sees:

1. *a* is of class *A*
2. *A* has a method display that takes an **int**
3. It knows how to turn an **Integer** into an **int**

Therefore it can use *display(int)* from class A. The compiler does **unbox** the Integer object into a primitive int value for you behind the covers.

And finally: in your scenario 1, you are **not** overriding anything. Your display method within B **does not override** anything in A - as it has **different signature**. Thus, you are still calling the method from A! You will notice that immediately, when putting @Override on your method in B!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a doubt here, In scenario 1, even though i have declared display(int i), the call to a.display(2) is refereing to display(Integer i) , though the closest mach is int datatype ?

Comment: See my updated answer. In scenario one, there is no overriding at all!

Answer (score 0):

let's say for understanding - JAVA tries to match the closest possible `Data type` in the parameter (given) to the parameters declared (overriden) by the called method. in both the cases `Object` being the Broadest Object every Object other than integer is considered as a simple `Object`. however, Thanks to JAVA's `Autoboxing`, `Integer` is first typed into `int` and therefore passed as an integer instead of an `Object`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a doubt here, In scenario 1, even though i have declared display(int i), the call to a.display(2) is refereing to display(Integer i) , though the closest mach is int datatype ?

Comment: The Deal in the first Scenario is that, the super class already contains a method which can take an Integer as an argument so instead of calling a sub-class' method JAVA wraps `int` to `Integer` and calls super class' method. note: overriding is no-where close to this, also avoid using such code.